# Visual Studio some projects in solution don't create exe files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, console-application

I have a solution with 3 projects in visual studio where one is wpf and the 2 other are console. The wpf project is built without problems as exe file but the two console projects get built as dll file but I need all projects as exe not dll file.

Comment: You most likely have set their Build-Type to "ClassLibrary" - change to "Executable" instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the output of the build process on the project preference page.

[image]

Keep in mind that converting from dll to .exe put some constraints as for example it needs to have a `Main` method.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2015/2017 you need to change project output type. Right click on project->Properties->Application->Output type->Console Application.